# How to transform a partial derivative to a directional derivative with respect to some affine parameter?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, calculus, geodesics

Suppose an affine parameter $\lambda$ is defined along a null geodesic with $dx^\mu/d\lambda=k^\mu$. How could I write the partial derivative $\partial f/\partial x^\mu$ by using $df/d\lambda$? If $k^\mu\neq0$ for all $\mu$, can I write $\partial f/\partial x^\mu=(1/k^\mu)df/d\lambda$?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible. The left hand side is a field over the manifold and the right hand side is defined only on the null geodesic. It’s okay to write $df/d\lambda = (\partial f/\partial x^\mu)(dx^\mu/d\lambda)$

Comment: ^ and the important thing is that there is a summation over $\mu$, which is why you can’t just ‘divide’ the $k^{\mu}$ from both sides.

Comment: But you can, in principle, dot both hand sides of the equation @Aiden has provided with $k^{\mu}$ and then solve wrt $\partial f/\partial x^{\mu}$ if you like